# When type hinting a class in PHP, do you need to include the class file?

Tags: php, type-hinting

If I have a class `Foo` and a function `bar`

```
function bar (Foo $x) { baz($x); }
```

that uses `Foo` as a type hint... do I need to include the file containing `Foo` in order for the above to compile?

In a test with PHP 5.4.33, including the class was not required, even when calling the function. The function failed, since the provided `$x` was not of type `Foo`, but no error such as "Error: Foo not defined" occurred.

Is this behavior dependable? Is it documented anywhere?

As a side note, I know that it could be good for documentation to include the `Foo.php` file when I'm using `Foo` as a type hint, but it does prevent a call to `require_once` if I don't have to include it.

Comment: This is why many people use autoloaders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an authoritative response.

I can imagine that PHP objects internally have a field where the class name is stored. This could be used for the argument check.

In the case where the object *is* a valid instance of `Foo` (and you want to use it) you will already need the definition of `Foo` else you can't make an instance.

So it seems like the argument check doesn't need the definition of `Foo`.

Answer (score 4):

All PHP does is check the *name* of the type. It does not link it to any concrete implementation. As such, it is not required in any way to have access to a concrete implementation of that type; meaning you do not need to `include` the file which defines the type.